# ADO Connection to MariaDB

Tags: c++, database, mariadb, ado

I try to connect in a C++ via Ado to a MariaDB Database.

```
CADODatabase m_dbConnection;
```

(my test.h)

```
m_dbConnection.SetConnectionString(strConnectionString);
m_dbConnection.SetConnectionTimeout(60);
```

Connection String is

```
DRIVER={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver}; Server=xx.xx.xx.xx.xx; Port=3306; database=db; UID=8001; password=********;
```

I tried to setup a DSN but I don´t know how the connection string has to look like?

```
DSN=Name;
```

Is it important if the program is a 32 or 64 bit version? which DSN is used in this case?

I always get the error:

```
Init(): Could not connect to database with connection string 'DSN=Cue1 DATABASE=yesdb'
Error message: Connection String = DSN=Cue1 DATABASE=yesdb
CADODataBase Error
Code = 80004005
Code meaning = Unspecified error
Source = Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
Description = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver 
specified
```

or

```
Init(): Could not connect to database with connection string 'Driver={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver} 
Server=xx.xx.xx.xx; Port=3306; database=db; UID=8001; password=xxxxxxx;Option=3;'
Error message: Connection String = Driver={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver} Server=xx.xx.xx.xx; Port=3306; 
database=db; UID=8001; password=xxxxxx;Option=3;
CADODataBase Error
Code = 80040e73
Code meaning = IDispatch error #3187
Source = Microsoft OLE DB Service Components
Description = Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB specification.`
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what library you're using to connect.

```
CADODatabase m_dbConnection;
```

I'm not used to seeing CADODatabase.   Your connection string looks like what I would expect using the MySQL ADODB library.  But usually raw ADO connection strings use a property called "Provider"...

Comment: Not sure why the down vote without explanation...    Here's some additional documentation to support OLE DB connection string  structure...  specific to Microsoft because ADO is/was a Microsoft construct..  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-oledbstr/774039da-09c1-4b24-b53b-8f9ae019830c.

Comment: Hey,
sorry the Downvote was not from me ! 
Thanks,  I will try to have a look again. any other Suggestions?
I need something to call a stored procedure!

Comment: Again, not sure what library you're using...   in the apps Ive written in C++ to connect to mariadb however, Ive always used their direct connector for C/C++.  Its actually for C... so not the most fun to use.... but but not too bad.  You can get it/read more about it here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-c/